# 1998 Ford E150 Van - Implementing Power Doors and Windows

Tags: electrical, ford, power-windows

I put different doors on my ford van that have power windows and locks.  My van was not equipped with these features originally.

How do I get power to the doors in order to make the windows and door locks function properly?

Comment: I cannot tell you specifically how to do it. Getting power to the doors/locks is not going to be the big issue. The big issue will be getting them to work as you'd expect. Most windows/locks work from a body control module (BCM) specific to the application. You'll probably need not only the BCM, but the wiring to go along with it. I know the BCM controls these things, but I would bet there is more to it than that. I'm not sure of how the BCM interfaces with the CAN Bus (if it does at all). An interesting problem.